# Query database globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am working on Blazor web application and came up with a problem. While using local SQL server it was not a problem, however after discovering world of databases and having some costs, I realized that I am probably having some design issue.

I am requesting data from Database that is updating constantly. I would like to query it, let's say every 10 minutes for possible updates. Currently I am doing it from every page where data is needed.

This way. Example of code behind from one of the pages:

```
private List<DataRecord> DataRecords { get; set; } = new List<DataRecord>();
this.DataRecords = await this.HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<DataRecord>>("api/DataRecord");
this.FilteredDataRecords = this.DataRecords.Where(w => w.TimeNow.Date == SelectedDate.Value.Date).OrderBy(o => o.TimeNow).ToList();
```

This would probably work fine, if there would be no need to pay for DB traffic. However if I need to request this from 5 pages, it is 5 times more requests. Is there a way to have some "global" class that would call for DB updates every 10 minutes and I would have possibility to access this data from every page of web app without a need to query every time am going to some page?

Or is it better to add some update = refresh button on every page? Just thinking is it anyway more "cheaper" to query every time user is accessing the page than call update timer every 10 minutes?

Comment: This sounds MUCH more complicated than you lead on. You're talking about cross-tab coordination, which on most browsers is impossible. Is this Blazor WebAssembly or Blazor Server?

Comment: What you are describing can be solved by having a singleton class that does the caching and querying of data.
Inject this singleton class into each page you need such data.
I am assuming you are familiar with the concept of "dependency injection" in asp.net core.
If not, that should be your starting point

Comment: What @Cerezo has said is a great place to start along with a way to have timed events that update the class. You could also have it in a cache with expiration time, but then you have the load delay every so often instead of having it updated in the background.

Comment: I am familiar with dependency injection. Was actually thinking about this way, but wanted to ask first, before building something. What is then the most typical solution used out there? Is it code behind and my current approach or Dependency Injection way with registering a singleton?

Comment: @LG3 It sort of depends. If you just want to have the content of the page automatically updated every 10 minutes, just have it fire an event on a timer to get new data from an endpoint; you seem to have api/datarecord. If you want something that is very speedy/performant, have an endpoint that updates your cache fire, either using something external like hangfire, Azure functions, or just an old fashioned TimedHostedService, to update the data you have cached and the endpoint returns that. The first method I mention is almost certainly the easiest.

Comment: By the way I am using Client, Server, Shared model. It is not hosted yet, just running on my own machine. All DB logic is in Server project and I am getting and sending data through API from client side.

Comment: How much do you think it will cost?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd use a javascript timer, rather than a service with a C# timer.  Then you can have your javascript call your Blazor data-loading method using JS Interop.  No DI is required, other than the JS Interop one built into Blazor.

Comment: I have not down-voted your answer, but I think it will continue to get down-votes, because it is not answering my original question about how to query a data... while accessing particular page or having a timer. There are different types of timers, but is more about what is the most efficient and commonly used approach for querying database.

Comment: People are free to downvote if they want.  But do you actually know how many SQL queries can be run by even a weak server per second, and how many kilobytes transfer you're talking, compared to serving say a single `.jpg` image?  I suspect you are wracking your brain to solve a problem that you'll never have, unless you are developing a site to compete with Netflix or Google.

Comment: As for your described problem, you'll have to describe your exact architecture.  Why do you think SQL data bandwidth is at a premium, but your server bandwidth (which is what you'd be using if you cached your data) is not?